# Background color suddenly changed after EditText lost focus

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using custom EditText which can clear its focus when we pressed back button

```
class ClearFocusEditText(context: Context, attr: AttributeSet): TextInputEditText(context, attr) {

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            clearFocus()
        }

        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

And this is my layout activity

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".ui.TestActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_32"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorManatee">

        <com.test.widgets.ClearFocusEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_et_survey"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_0"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_0"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_16"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_12"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextContent.Body2"
            android:textColor="@color/selector_et_survey"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:hint="Test" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

I had run this on my API 30 emulator, this is the normal screen.

[image: Normal Background color]

After i type some text and press back button afterwards, the EditText lost its focus and the focus moved to its parent which is LinearLayout. But the Background suddenly changed the color. Some solution to this problem would be very helpful, Thank you.

[image: Weird Background color]

Comment: Don't use android:background="@drawable/shape_et_survey" in the TextInputEditText

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti it's still exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving the focus from my TextInputEditText either with clearFocus() or requesting the focus from one of its containers I continued have the same problem. The problem was that the background just changed to a reddish pale color. I looked with a Layout inspector in real time and it showed another layer created by the system on the top of all my existing layers, that was the cause. Another extra click was necessary to fix the whole thing and to make it disappear getting back the original white background.

I solved by creating another dummy  off stage TextView with id:gone. My TextInputEditText view is the one with binding id:searchTextInputEditText.

```
    binding.searchTextInputEditText.clearFocus();
    binding.gone.requestFocus()
```

After requesting the focus from the gone view my background reddish problem disappeared. I also tried inverting the order of the above instructions and tried also with only one of the two: nothing else worked.

Below you can find the xml for clarity:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/roottag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".Product_Search_FR">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-200dp"

        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="_"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelproductname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Product search"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_TextInputLayout"
                style="?attr/textInputOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="e.g. ashtray"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/stripe_ic_search">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_TextInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="30sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.19"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutCompat2">

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:id="@+id/map_or_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_TextInputLayout" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="map" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutCompat2">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/search_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="com.hotellina.SouvenirScout.product_result_FR"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"

            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_product_result__f_r" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```